# Check if specific chars were written and trigger an error

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Im trying to figure out via JS if invalid chars were entered in a textarea

I want to allow only this chars:

```
A-Za-z0-9 !#%&*()+-=,.?"';:/
```

If illegal chars were entered, I want to retrieve the bad chars, and trigger an error, i.e:

Invalid text, bad chars were written:

```
1) _
2) @
etc...
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you are ok with using jquery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812585/jquery-validate-characters-on-keypress

Comment: At what point do you want to do this check?

Comment: I want to make the check onsubmit

Comment: It wasn't clear, do you want to allow a space?  What about an underscore?

Comment: no underscore, allow spaces .
this are the only chars i want to allow: A-Za-z0-9 !#%&*()+-=,.?"';:/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure when you want to do this check, but here's a function to do the checking. It will alert the first non-valid character.

```
function checkValue(input) {
    var result = /[^a-z0-9 !#%&*()+\-=,.?"';:\/]/i.exec(input.value);
    if (result) {
        alert("Character '" + result[0] + "' is not allowed");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want all the matched non-valid characters, then you could use the following:

```
function checkValue(input) {
    var isValid = true, result, matchedChars = [];
    while( (result = /[^a-z0-9 !#%&*()+\-=,.?"';:\/]/ig.exec(input.value)) ) {
        matchedChars.push("'" + result[0] + "'");
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        alert("Characters " + matchedChars.join(", ") + " are not allowed");
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: This regex doesn't allow spaces, which the OP said he wanted.

Comment: So he did, I missed that. Though I think the OP did edit the question to make that clearer after I'd started writing my answer. Anyway, fixed now.

Comment: you don't need to escape dots or quantifiers inside the character class

Comment: However, you *do* need to escape hyphens if they're in the middle (like they are here - the range `+-=` means `<` will be incorrectly included).

Comment: SilentGhost, Peter: good points, thanks. Also, there's no need to escape parentheses inside a character class. Fixed now.