# Javascript/Jquery validating decimal input on keypress/keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, keydown

I'm trying to find a way to validate a text input on key press, I want to allow numbers only inside my text input including decimals.

I was taking the approach of using jQuery.keydown, and checking what the key was and using event.preventDefault() if the key was not in the allowed list. But since then I've read that keys aren't consistent throughout browsers and I'm also worries about different OS's.

I've come across this question but I'm not fluent in regex and not sure whether this would suit my needs:
[jquery - validate characters on keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812585/jquery-validate-characters-on-keypress)

With that approach a regex that expects 00.00 would stop the user when 00. is typed in since the regex is checked upon key up.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not rely on key events as that would mean the validation would fail if the user does a *right-click -> paste* with invalid characters.

What you should instead do is use something like zurb's `textchanged` event - which will accurately trigger regardless of the mode of input (key, paste, drag and drop, whatever)

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Inside your `textchanged` handler, you can put in the appropriate regex to deal with decimals.

Comment: I've used this as I found it very good and easy to use and also applied Snake Eyes's answer in the way I needed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you want to restrict input (as opposed to validation), you could work with the key events. something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="numbersOnly" value="" />
```

And:

```
jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

**or**, we can update this after the user has 'left' the field, with the on change event, this way the user can still navigate through the text with the arrow keys.

```
jQuery('.numbersOnly').on('change', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

This immediately lets the user know that they can't enter alpha characters, etc. rather than later during the validation phase.

You'll still want to validate because the input might be filled in by cutting and pasting with the mouse or possibly by a form autocompleter that may not trigger the key events.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/eu7P9/

Comment: Thanks mate, also you'll not be able to use the arrow keys to navigate through text, you'll have to add custom functionality for that, I just don't have the time!

Comment: I can do that on change rather than keyup, so it would cover pasting etc.

But apart from that, that regex allows multiple decimal points.

Comment: @MatthewGrima: See my updated code. It avoids multiple dots `.` in your input

Answer (score 3):

I have used e.which to validate the decimal numbers

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var isEnable=true;
$(".only-number-period").live('keydown', function (e) {
    //isEnable = (e.which != 110) ? false : true;
        if( ((e.which == 9) || (e.which == 46) || (e.which == 8) || (e.which == 110) || (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which >= 96 && e.which <= 105))){
            if(isEnable ==false && e.which ==110){return false;}
        }else{
        return false
        }  
    if (isEnable == true) {            
    isEnable=(e.which ==110)?false:true;
        }
    });
});​
```

link::http://jsfiddle.net/rTr2w/

Answer (score 2):

using [Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683943/shannon-hochkins)'s answer, I provide the following simple JS code:

```
jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function () {
    if(($(this).val().split(".")[0]).indexOf("00")>-1){
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace("00","0"));
    } else {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
    }
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/SnakeEyes/eu7P9/2/

**update**
To avoid multiple `.` symbol, use the following code:

```
jQuery('.numbersOnly').keyup(function (e) {
    if(($(this).val().split(".")[0]).indexOf("00")>-1){
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace("00","0"));
    } else {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
    }

    if($(this).val().split(".")[2] != null || ($(this).val().split(".")[2]).length ){
        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().lastIndexOf(".")));
    }   
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SnakeEyes/eu7P9/3/